# Drawing lines in a PictureBox

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, gdi+, picturebox

First I need to make some color scribbles (the picture below is taken from M. Yang article's on Still Image Colorization) on an monochrome input image which is loaded into a PictureBox control.

[image]

I'm trying to use this to get the effect:

```
private void PictureBoxOnMouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        this.MouseInitialPosition = e.Location;
    }
}

private void PictureBoxOnMouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        this.MouseLastPosition = e.Location;
    }
    this._PictureBox.Invalidate();
}

private void PictureBoxOnPaint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using(var pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3.0F))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, this.MouseInitialPosition, this.MouseLastPosition);
    }
}
```

But that's giving me not quite I've been waiting for:

- I can't put several lines. Lines are not stored;
- I'm overwriting line with line;

Second. I need to get all pixels from an image I've been drawing onto and filter them in some way (i.e. extract special ones). How do I store lines/scribbles onto image and then read the image efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to store lines when a mouseMove event occurs on a picturebox control and then invalidate to redraw:

```
public class Lines
{
    public Point startPoint = new Point();
    public Point endPoint = new Point();
}

Lines l = new Lines();
List<Lines> allLines = new List<Lines>();

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Collect endPoint when mouse moved
    if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        l.endPoint = e.Location;
        //Line completed
        allLines.Add(l);
        this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Collect startPoint when left mouse clicked
    if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        l = new Lines();
        l.startPoint = e.Location;
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var aLine in allLines)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, aLine.startPoint, aLine.endPoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a list of lines. Then when OnPaint is called draw all the lines.

The Line class would be something like:

```
public class Line
{
    public List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();

    public DrawLine(Pen pen, Grphics g)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Points.Count - 1; ++i)
            g.DrawLine(pen, Points[i], Points[i+1];
    }
}

private void PictureBoxOnMouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        var newLine = new Line();
        newLine.Points.Add(e.Location);
        lines.Add(newLine);
    }
}

PictureBoxOnMouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        lines[lines.Count-1].Points.Add(e.Location);
    }
}

private void PictureBoxOnPaint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using(var pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3.0F))
    {
        foreach (var line in lines)
            DrawLine(pen, e.Graphics)
    }
 }
```

Comment: While dragging, you generate a lot of mouse move events. In this code all these events result in adding a line. After one drag you'll end up with a lot of lines in the lines collection, while you wanted one line per drag. The proper way to do this is to add the line not after each mouse move, but at the end of the drag = mouse up event.

Comment: @HaraldDutch, the OP is asking about scribbles not lines.